# How to add class in the <tr> for react-table in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am working in React js and I already implemented the common component for the react-table

I am using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) library for the table.

I need to add the custom class for some specific rows.

I already try to add couple of row props as well but i didn't get success in that.

Here is my table example

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTable, useExpanded } from 'react-table';

function Table({ className, colSpan, columns, data }) {
// Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state: { expanded },
} = useTable(
    {
        className,
        colSpan,
        columns,
        data,
    },
    useExpanded // Use the useExpanded plugin hook
);

// Render the UI for your table
return (
    <table className={className} {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                            {column.render('Header')}
                        </th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return (
                                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                </td>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
            {rows.length === 0 && (
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan={colSpan}>No Record Found</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Pass the className inside the PropsMethods.

```
<tr {...row.getRowProps({className: 'row'})}>
      {row.cells.map(cell => {
       return <td {...cell.getCellProps({className: 'cell'})}> 
           {cell.render('Cell')}</td>
            })}
   </tr>
```

[Here](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic) is an example of what you would possibly like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Quarks, but i would like to pass the className value dynamically from the data which we pass in the table

Comment: Have you tried passing the passing the classname parameter into the className field.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to add a class or multiple classes to some specific rows in your table based on some criteria.

Let's say you have to apply a class to every row with an even index. This can be achieved like so:

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                    <tr 
                      className = {i%2 === 0? "your-classname": null} 
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                    >
                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return (
                                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                </td>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
            {rows.length === 0 && (
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan={colSpan}>No Record Found</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
```

If you want to avoid writing logic inside your tags then you can also use the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package. It will make your code look cleaner and easy to read.

My answer is only valid if you are conditionally trying to add classes to your rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rishabh, Yes you are right that I would like to add the className based on the condition,  but I would like to pass the className value dynamically from the data which we pass in the table